# git log graph - не верная последовательность, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: git, git-log

Всем привет, изучаю git. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с git log graph, как правильно прочитать. У меня почему-то эта команда отображает не верную последовательность коммитов, хотя возможно я не понимаю до конца как она работает.

Есть простой реп:

1. git init
2. echo '1' >> 1.txt
3. git commit -a -m '1-й коммит на мастер'
4. git checkout -b testing
5. echo '2' >> 1.txt
6. git commit -a -m '2-й коммит на testing'
7. git checkout master
8. echo '3' >> 1.txt
9. git commit -a -m '3-й коммит на мастер'
10. git merge testing, здесь получаю конфликт, разрешаю его
11. git commit -a -m 'конфликт на мастер'

Выполняю:
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему git log --graph показывает, что коммит **e90f872** идет после **5ad289d** ?

Ведь **e90f872** сделан раньше ? Это видно по времени.

Когда убираю опцию --graph, то последовательность верная.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log `git log --graph --date-order`

Comment: Спасибо Алексей. Очень помогли, теперь буду знать.